# Compare two columns and increment count when same

Tags: c#, mysql, windows

I am working with MySQL db. I have 2 columns action and expected. I need to generate test step ID based on a combination i.e when both combinations are unique then add a new ID say TS01. But when action already exists and expected is different I need to have an ID like TS01-01. Below is the sample table. I'm not finding any approach to solve this.

```
+--------+----------+--------+
| Action | Expected | stepid |
+--------+----------+--------+
| a      | b        | TS1    |
| a      | c        | TS1-01 |
| a      | d        | TS1-02 |
| a      | b        | TS1    |
| b      | a        | TS2    |
| b      | c        | TS2-01 |
+--------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Wait, can you elaborate more? As I can see, the stepid for the 4th action 'a' is `TS1` whereas should be `TS1-03`.

Comment: I saw this guy saying this, there's no feedback on it but the guy wants to do almost the same as you.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17518606/3239917

Comment: @christia , it has TS1 as that combination already exists in the table. and its fetching that already assigned id

Answer (score 0):

you need a second table to hold a counter for each action

every time you create a new entry in your table above, you can use that counter to generate the index to TS1-XX

EDIT:

ok, obviously the answer wasn't clear enough ...

you have a table with 3 columns: Action, Expected and stepid

I will call this table T1

you will need an additional table ... let's call it T2

with the columns: Action, counter1 and counter2

counter1 and counter 2 are int columns

counter1 -> auto increment, start at 1

counter 2 default to 0

now for each unique Action in T1, create a new row in T2

as you can see you will get something like this for T2

```
+--------+----------+----------+  
| Action | counter1 | counter2 |  
+--------+----------+----------+  
| a      | 1        | 0        |  
| b      | 2        | 0        |  
| c      | 3        | 0        |  
| d      | 4        | 0        |  
+--------+----------+----------+
```

now back to T1

```
+--------+----------+--------+  
| Action | Expected | stepid |  
+--------+----------+--------+  
| a      | b        | TS1    |  
| a      | c        | TS1-01 |  
| a      | d        | TS1-02 |  
| a      | b        | TS1    |  
| b      | a        | TS2    |  
| b      | c        | TS2-01 |  
+--------+----------+--------+
```

if you take a closer look at stepid, you can see that for every Action a stepid begins with TS1 ... for every action b stepid begins with TS2 ...

now let's take into account that there is more than one row in T1 for every Action
if counter2 for that action is 0, then your stepid is just the TSx part

if counter2 is greater than 0, stepid is "TSx-YY" where YY is the two digit repesentation of counter2's value ...

with every unique "Expected" you insert for a specific Action, increment counter2 for that action

now look at counter1 of T2 for action a and b ... that is **1** for "a" (TS **1** ) and **2** for "b" (TS **2** )

now let's take into account that Action and Expected may not be unique, but should be treated as unique when it comes to stepid generation

simply check if the tuple you want to insert is already in T1 and read step ID from there if it exists ... if not, generate stepid the way i mentioned above

EDIT2:

n is the new row being inserted into T1 while n[action] is the column action of the new row, etc.

m is the row retrieved from T2, or null if no row was returned

pseudo code for inserting a row into T1:

```
if (Execute SQL returns a row: SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE action = n[action] and expected = n[expected])
  return // do not insert twice, or as an alternative, fetch that stepid and use it

m <- Execute SQL: SELECT * FROM T2 where action = n[action]

if( m == null )
{
  Execute SQL: INSERT INTO T2 SET action = n[action]
  m <- Execute SQL: SELECT * FROM T2 where action = n[action]
}
//m has a row now
_stepid = "TS"
_stepid += m[counter1].ToString()
if( m[counter2] > 0 )
{
  _stepid += "-"
  _stepid += m[counter2].ToString("D2") // will get 3 as "03" and 11 as "11"
}
Execute SQL: INSERT INTO T1 SET action = n[action], expected = n[expected], stepid = _stepid
Execute SQL: UPDATE T2 set counter2=counter2 + 1 WHERE action = n[action]
```

Comment: can i get any example as i have not worked with index.

Comment: index != SQL index ... by index i mean the 2 digits you add to whatever step id you have ... that XX in TS1-XX

Comment: please refer any similar posts as i dont have knowledge on indexes.

Comment: you are mixing things up ... forget about the word "index" ... call it "suffix" in this case ... if you have the stepid "TS1" and you add something so it becomes "TS1-01" ... that something ("-01") is a suffix ... DO NOT mix this up with database indexes since it has NOTHING to do with it

Comment: Ok. i can generate XX. But how will i generate TS1

Comment: you could add an auto increment column to the second table, and use that value to generate "TS*" in the same way

Comment: i cant add auto increment to the column. then i will get TS1, TS2, TS3 for a,b a,c a,d. This is not what i want. Please read the question again

Comment: ok, obviously my answer wasn't clear enough for you... added some more details

Comment: ok.Thankx for the explanation. Am not able to go with the coding for this explanation for counter 2.
if counter2 is greater than 0, stepid is "TSx-YY" where YY is the two digit repesentation of counter2's value ...

with every unique "Expected" you insert for a specific Action, increment counter2 for that action

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
`Action`, `Expected`,
(
SELECT concat("TS",`Action`,if(count(*)=1,"",concat("-",count(*)-1)))
FROM <table> t2
WHERE 
concat(t2.`Action`,t2.`Expected`)=concat(t1.`Action`,t1.`Expected`)
) as `step_id`
FROM
<table> t1    
;
```

Thanks

Comment: yes i could not execute the query. error in sql syntax at "select concat "line

Comment: Wait, how do you mean by unique??? a b appears twice they are not unique btw. And then you said action is present and expected is diff?? How do you mean that, i mean this applies to the first row as well.

Comment: Unique in the sense i meant if the combination of action and expected already exists in db then get the existing id else create a new id. and from the above updated ans am getting error as t2.concat does not exist

Comment: What you mean is if a,b appears twice in the able set_id would get the value of "TSa-01", and if a,c appears once it would get the value only "TSa", and if b,a appears trice it would get the value "TSb-02" like this.
Above query behave similar.
Just a minor change in the query t1/t2 would go inside of concat

Comment: even now am getting syntax error. The db am using is mysql

Comment: Tell me the table structure. What you have in t1 and t2

Comment: whats the error you are getting? I'm following the tables what you have provided in the question